# Is it possible to eliminate the mass left joins and simplify this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All -

If you look below, I'm joining the same table on itself literally 104 times.  The reason I am doing this is because for each weeks out , I need the entire 104 weeks of weeks out values FROM each Row's starting point.  In other words for 0 weeks out, I need 104 weeks worth of values, and for 1 week out, I need 104 weeks worth of values, etc.

If you look at the query and data snapshots below, it should give you a better sense of what I'm hoping to achieve.

[Base Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPaSv.png)

[Using my query below, the data looks like this, but it's super manual, takes forever to run, and I cannot easily pivot the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt67p.png)

[I think ideally the data would look like this, but I'm lost on how to alter the joins and structure to make that happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqLSr.png)

```
select 
a.*
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) as wo
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(b.upb)/ sum(b.ila) as w1
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(c.upb)/ sum(c.ila) as w2
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(d.upb)/ sum(d.ila) as w3
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(e.upb)/ sum(e.ila) as w4
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(f.upb)/sum(f.ila) as w5
,sum(a.upb)/ sum(a.ila) - sum(g.upb)/sum(g.ila) as w6
from
scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 a
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 b on b.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 1 = b.weeks_out
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 c on c.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 2 = c.weeks_out
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 d on d.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 3 = d.weeks_out
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 e on e.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 4 = e.weeks_out
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 f on f.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 5 = f.weeks_out
left join scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 g on g.loan_id = a.loan_id and a.weeks_out + 6 = g.weeks_out

where a.loan_id = '2200835473524998'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Please a) simplify your example much more! (e.g. better understandable table and column names, only a three or for joins instead of 6 or 7). b) Explain what you want to do - it is not very obvious. For that please add some sample data as text, not as image. This should only contain a few columns (e.g. id, weeks_id, upd, ila). For this sample you should show the expected output.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you think you need `GROUP BY` and `SUM` here. Your sample data shows exactly one row per loan ID and week, so there is nothing to aggregate. All you seem to want is to peep into the following rows. Use `LEAD` for this.

```
select 
  tuc.*,
  upb / ila as wo,
  1 - (lead(upb, 1) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w1,
  1 - (lead(upb, 2) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w2,
  1 - (lead(upb, 3) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w3,
  1 - (lead(upb, 4) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w4,
  1 - (lead(upb, 5) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w5,
  1 - (lead(upb, 6) over (order by weeks_out) / ubp) as w6
from scratchpad.term_upb_cube1 tuc
where loan_id = 2200835473524998
order by weeks_out;
```